# How to get hidden form from task bar to front in C# winform? From class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am doing it from a class, because I've got code to make it so only one instance can work. I've seen lots of forums and just cannot figure it out. I've tried all sorts of methods like Application.OpenForms etc, nothing is working. The last form which was closed will be hidden in the taskbar. I just want to be able to bring that hidden form.

```
namespace EncryptionDecryption
{
    static class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        bool instanceCountOne = false;

        using (Mutex mtex = new Mutex(true, "MyRunningApp", out instanceCountOne))
        {
            if (instanceCountOne)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Login("", ""));
                mtex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("An instance of this application is already running in the taskbar", "Note");
                mtex.ReleaseMutex();

                Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

                //Trying to pass the loggedinusername and role to new instance of the program so dont have to sign in again...
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what would Application.OpenForms gives?

Comment: Iv started using this solution which also helped me keep my arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the above I used this which plays with threads to make sure I only have one instance and it will open that one instance only with new parameters to! Which i really needed for my next step!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5bcfc8a-bf69-4bbc-923d-f30f9ecf5f64/single-instance-application?forum=csharpgeneral